# Is there a way to make Firebase hosting non-case-sensitive?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase hosting, and I am wondering if there is a way to make the links on my Firebase-hosted site case-insensitive?  Many people may be typing them directly into their browser instead of following links.  (Don't ask...I realize that's ridiculous, but it's a totally different conversation.)

I ran `firebase -help` but don't see a configuration option for it, nor do I see that option on the Hosting tab on Forge.

If there is no option for case-insensitive hosting, is there any way to accomplish this on a file system that is case-insensitive?  I can't create lower- or mixed-case versions of the folders, because my file system sees them as the same name.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase redirects use [glob pattern matching](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), so you could do something like this:

```
{
   "source" : "/[Ff][Oo][Oo]",
   "destination" : "/Foo",
   "type" : 301
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the above does indeed work. The document linked mentions "Globs inside [[ and case commands are matched case-insensitive".  Unfortunately, I have confirmed that no variant of surrounding a string in [[ and ]] works to compare in a case-insensitive fashion in the firebase.json file.

Comment: Where do you add these lines?

Comment: I have been able to use: `"source" : "/[Hh][Oo][Ll][Ii][Dd][Aa][Yy]2020"` for non-dynamic links, but when I try to use the same type of solution for dynamicLinks prefix configs: `"source": "/[Ll][Ii][Nn][Kk][Ss]/**","dynamicLinks": true` I am not getting the results I expect.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase hosting is case-sensitive. It doesn't have an option to work non-case-sensitive.

Your best bet is to fix the problem at the source and ensure all your files are named consistently. This question on SuperUser might be of help there: https://superuser.com/questions/599955/make-every-file-in-a-directory-structure-lowercase-windows

Comment: Ya, that's what I was afraid of.  I actually do have them all cased consistently, I just want them to work for any combination.

I'll submit a feature request to add a case-insensitive option.

Comment: Hey Frank, I discovered a way to (mostly) handle this with redirects, and posted it as a separate answer...it's not exactly what I wanted but it is a 99% solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have just discovered that there is a way to add redirects using firebase hosting (details here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html), and I can effectively use this to solve 99% of this problem.

I added a redirect like this:

```
{
   "source" : "/foo",
   "destination" : "/Foo",
   "type" : 301
}
```

So if anyone types in the lowercase version, they get 301'd to the correct link.  Works like a charm!!

Comment: Cool. I didn't think it would cover your needs, but if it does: awesome!